# How does Node Buffer.lastIndexOf byteOffset work?

Tags: node.js, buffer

From the Node documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_lastindexof_value_byteoffset_encoding

```
const buf = Buffer.from('this buffer is a buffer');

console.log(buf.lastIndexOf('buffer'));
// Prints: 17
```

That makes sense to me, however these do not:

```
console.log(buf.lastIndexOf('buffer', 5));
// Prints: 5

console.log(buf.lastIndexOf('buffer', 4));
// Prints: -1
```

Why would the index of `('buffer', 5)` not be 17? Why is the index of `('buffer', 4)` -1 instead of 17?

Node doc says:

- byteOffset:  Where to begin searching in `buf`. If negative, then offset is calculated from the end of buf. Default: buf.length - 1.

The default value of `buf.length - 1` implies that it searches backwards through the Buffer, which would explain `lastIndexOf('buffer', 5) = 5` but it doesn't explain `lastIndexOf('buffer', 4) = -1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search starts at the specified index *and works backwords from there*.  So in your example, when the offsetIndex is `5`, it finds the first buffer (because it's searching right to left).  But when you specify `4`, there's no more "buffer" occurances to the left of that index, so it returns -1.